# How can I know the original cell index of detailed table view?

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

I implemented searchbar. It works okay when I only search for food. But When I try to edit the food from the search result, it only changes the search result array(foodSearching) but not for the original array(foods). So I need to know the indexpath for the original array(foods) when I edit the table view. Is there any help?

`selectedIndexPath` is different for 'foodSearching' array (temporary array to show search result) and 'foods' array (original array to hold all of the data)

```
@IBAction func unwindToFoodList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? FoodViewController, food = sourceViewController.food {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing food.
            if(isSearching){
                foodSearching[selectedIndexPath.row] = food

                // foodSearching array is temporary..
                //need to find indexpath for foods array(original array)and update it as well...!!

                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

            }else{
                foods[selectedIndexPath.row] = food
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            }

        } else {
            // Add a new food.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: foods.count, inSection: 0)
            foods.append(food)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
        // Save the foods.
        saveFoods()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't edit a cell. Edit your data model and then let the table reload.  Unless your model is massive just reload the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using `indexPath` as the reference to data since `indexPath` can change.  If you were using Core Data, I would suggest `objectID`, but if you're not, I would suggest using any other uniquely identifiable information and use that as the reference.  Creating following helper functions can help your implementation:

```
func indexPath(forFoodWithID uniqueID: IDType) -> NSIndexPath?
func foodID(forFoodAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> IDType?
```

I hope that helps.